# Functioning Socket read no longer works when called in AsyncTask

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm making an app that sends a string to a server over a socket and then reads the output after the server has processed that data. It worked perfectly when it was my foreground task, but I have since used AsyncTask to show a process dialog while the socket communication runs in the background, and things start breaking after I read the output from the server and then try to close the socket.

```
private class Progressor extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ClearTalkInputActivity.this, "Loading..", "Analyzing Text", true, false);
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String language = strings[0].toLowerCase();
            String the_text = strings[1];
            Socket socket = null; 
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream dis = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(my_ip, port);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(language+"****"+the_text);
                String in = "";
                while (in.indexOf("</content>") < 0) {
                    in += dis.readUTF();    
                }
                socket.close();

                save_str(OUTPUT_KEY, in);   


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (dos != null) {
                try {
                    dos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dis != null) {
                try {
                    dis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 

            return null;
        }


    protected void onPostExecute() {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(new Intent (output_intent));
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting breakpoints wehn you have multiple threads is a little different.  Did you make sure you have the correct thread open when doing the debugging?  You really need to be able to see what's going on line by line.  Look upper left to see what threads you have and their status.

Comment: Checked again, and yeah. Turns out the problem happens at socket.close().

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way in Android is to use one of the two included HttpClients:

[Apache HTTP Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

There is no need to use sockets directly. These clients do a lot to improve your experience.

Here is a blog article by the Android developers, that explain the basics: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: Thanks. Although why would calling socket.close() cause an error?

Comment: Just a guess, but are you sure that socket != null?

Comment: I am now. Right now, according to the debugger, the execution of that is going fine (I don't know why that suddenly changed, but whatever). But I get to the end of doInBackground and it just hangs and doesn't go to onPostExecute.

Comment: It now works after I changed the type of doInBackground from Void to Boolean and did something with the result. I have no idea why that happened, but I'll go with that.